# How to get a free slot down a binary tree using the adjacency tree method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am building a website that requires users to join under a referrer. The structure of the data is supposed to be binary so if the referrer already has two children in their immediate downline, then the referred new user has to be slotted under one of the users under the referrer's downline, preferrably the first user to have been referred to prevent them from having more than two users directly under them. I'm building this system with codeigniter and my code is like this

```
public function get_referred_by($refer_id)
{
    $where = array('referral_id' => $refer_id);
    $parent = $this->get_by($where, true);
    $children = $this->db->select('referral_id')
                ->where('refer_id', $parent->referral_id)
                ->order_by('users.id desc')
                ->limit('2')
                ->get('users')->result();
    if(count($children) > 1)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i<count($children); $i++) 
        {
            $parent = $this->get_referred_by($children[$i]->referral_id);
        }
    }       
    return $parent; 
}
```

the problem is that with that code, i'm able to skip downlines to find the next open slot, but instead of first moving across a downline to check if the next user has free slots, the system is stuck on one single tree. for example,
user A joins users B and C,
then B joins D and E, 
what i want is when user As' ref id is used, instead of returning user Ds' ref number it returns user Cs'. Please help

Comment: Why make this a binary tree? Why not make it an N-ary tree (a parent can have any number of direct children)? The Adjacency List method works really well for N-ary trees.

Comment: The system requires a binary tree. Each user should have a maximum of two users directly under them

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to pick the earlier (leftmost) child, then there is no need to loop over the children, just pick the first one:

```
if(count($children) > 1)
{
    $parent = $parent = $this->get_referred_by($children[0]->referral_id);
}
```

Comment: That is actually what's happening when I run my code but what i want to do instead is if the left most child has 2 children then it should check if the right child has an empty slot i.e 1 child and place a child there

Comment: Won't that automatically happen at the level above, since it will not be true that `count($children) > 1`?